# How can I update / set Mask of telerik RadMaskedTextBox at client side (using javascript / jquery)

Tags: telerik, masking, radmaskedtextbox

I want to set / update mask of telerik RadMaskedTextBox at client side. Please help !

```
 <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" 
  ID="txtTest" Mask="(###) ###-####">
 </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
```